# Alegreya prevents nested \emph commands to behave as expected

Tags: fonts, emphasis

I'm using Alegreya font with PDFLaTeX, and have noticed that the `\emph` command did not work anymore when nested. To be clearer, this code :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\begin{document}
Normal text. \emph{Emphasized text.} \emph{Emphasized text including \emph{emphasized} text.}
\end{document}
```

yields :

[image: Alegreya prevents nested \emph from working properly]

instead of the regular nested behaviour (when another or no font is selected) : [image]

Any ideas on how to circumvent this problem ?

Comment: It's another bug of the Alegreya font metric files: the relevant parameter in the italic font is zero, so LaTeX can't distinguish that the font is italic.

Comment: The most recent update of the Alegreya font didn't fix this but, but solved the other one. When you'll have the new release (it will be in TeX Live 2014), forget about `\adjustalegreyaxheight`, but the hack remains essentially the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's another bug in the metric files for the Alegreya font. None of the italic or slanted fonts has the correct value in `\fontdimen1`. You can use the same workaround I proposed for [How can some eastern European diacritics be correctly displayed with the Alegreya font and pdftex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178516/how-can-some-eastern-european-diacritics-be-correctly-displayed-with-the-alegrey) modified for taking also into account the value in `\fontdimen1`, but you should file a bug report.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{}
\newcommand{\adjustalegreyaxheight}{\fontdimen5\font=\fontcharht\font`x }
\newcommand{\adjustalegreyaslant}{\fontdimen1\font=0.25pt }

\makeatletter
\let\Alegreya@@scale\@empty
%%% uncomment the next line if you want to scale the font,
%%% changing the value to what suits you
% \def\Alegreya@@scale{s*[0.9]}%
\makeatother

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{k}{n}{
      <-> \Alegreya@@scale Alegreya-Black-lf-t1
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{k}{it}{
      <-> \Alegreya@@scale Alegreya-BlackItalic-lf-t1
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{k}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-LF/k/it
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{b}{n}{
      <-> \Alegreya@@scale Alegreya-Bold-lf-t1
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{b}{it}{
      <-> \Alegreya@@scale Alegreya-BoldItalic-lf-t1
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{b}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-LF/b/it
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{m}{n}{
      <-> \Alegreya@@scale Alegreya-Regular-lf-t1
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{m}{it}{
      <-> \Alegreya@@scale Alegreya-Italic-lf-t1
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{m}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-LF/m/it
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{bx}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-LF/b/sl
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{bx}{n}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-LF/b/n
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-LF}{bx}{it}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-LF/b/it
}{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}

\usepackage{Alegreya}

\begin{document}

Normal text. \emph{Emphasized text.} \emph{Emphasized text including \emph{emphasized} text.}


The x-height: \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\the\fontdimen5\font}

The height of `x': \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\the\fontcharht\font`x}

Rodion \^{S}edrin

\u{U}ladz\`{i}m\`{i}r Damarackij

V\^{a}\v{c}\`{e}sla\u{u} Kuzn\^{a}co\u{u} 

\footnotesize

The x-height: \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\the\fontdimen5\font}

The height of `x': \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\the\fontcharht\font`x}

Rodion \^{S}edrin

\u{U}ladz\`{i}m\`{i}r Damarackij

V\^{a}\v{c}\`{e}sla\u{u} Kuzn\^{a}co\u{u} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've left the bits in the other answer, for completeness.

### Explanation

In order to see if a font is slanted, LaTeX examines the parameter `\fontdimen1` in the current font. If this is zero, LaTeX assumes it's upright.

### More flexible hack

Here is code that should take care of all the four combination (lining/oldstyle, tabular/nontabular) for figures, so that `Alegreya` can be called with any option.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%%%% HACK BEGINS
\def\adjustalegreyaslant{\fontdimen1\font=0.25pt }
\def\adjustalegreyaxheight{}
%%%% remove the following when you have Alegreya
%%%% with the date 2014-01-18 (or later)
\def\adjustalegreyaxheight{\fontdimen5\font=\fontcharht\font`x }

\begingroup\makeatletter
%%% scale option
\let\alegreyascale\@empty
%%% uncomment the next line if you want to scale the font,
%%% changing the value to what suits you
% \def\alegreyascale{s*[0.9]}
%% spaces and end of lines are ignored
\catcode`\ =9 \endlinechar=-1
\newcommand\adjustallalegreyafamilies[2]{
  \def\alegreyasuffix{#1}\def\alegreyainfix{#2}
  \DeclareFontFamily{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{k}{n}{
      <-> \alegreyascale Alegreya-Black-\alegreyainfix-t1
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{k}{it}{
      <-> \alegreyascale Alegreya-BlackItalic-\alegreyainfix-t1
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{k}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix/k/it
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{b}{n}{
      <-> \alegreyascale Alegreya-Bold-\alegreyainfix-t1
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{b}{it}{
      <-> \alegreyascale Alegreya-BoldItalic-\alegreyainfix-t1
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{b}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix/b/it
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{m}{n}{
      <-> \alegreyascale Alegreya-Regular-\alegreyainfix-t1
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{m}{it}{
      <-> \alegreyascale Alegreya-Italic-\alegreyainfix-t1
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{m}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix/m/it
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{bx}{sl}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix/b/sl
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{bx}{n}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix/b/n
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight}
  %
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix}{bx}{it}{
      <-> ssub * Alegreya-\alegreyasuffix/b/it
  }{\adjustalegreyaxheight\adjustalegreyaslant}
}
% execute the above for all four combinations
\adjustallalegreyafamilies{LF}{lf}
\adjustallalegreyafamilies{OsF}{osf}
\adjustallalegreyafamilies{TLF}{tlf}
\adjustallalegreyafamilies{TOsF}{tosf}
\endgroup
%%%%% HACK ENDS
%%%% now you can load the Alegreya package with the desired options
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}

\begin{document}

0123456789{\bfseries 0123456789}{\itshape 0123}{\slshape 0123}

Normal text. \emph{Emphasized text.} \emph{Emphasized text including \emph{emphasized} text.}


The x-height: \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\the\fontdimen5\font}

The height of `x': \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\the\fontcharht\font`x}

Rodion \^{S}edrin

\u{U}ladz\`{i}m\`{i}r Damarackij

V\^{a}\v{c}\`{e}sla\u{u} Kuzn\^{a}co\u{u} 

\footnotesize

The x-height: \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\the\fontdimen5\font}

The height of `x': \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\the\fontcharht\font`x}

Rodion \^{S}edrin

\u{U}ladz\`{i}m\`{i}r Damarackij

V\^{a}\v{c}\`{e}sla\u{u} Kuzn\^{a}co\u{u} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I always thought checking `\fontdimen1` was an odd way for `\em` to be implemented; in early XeTeX days this was a frequent problem with poorly-implemented fonts. `fontspec` patches `\em` to simply uses the current NFSS shape, which is more reliable. (You probably know that already though.)

Comment: Your solution works, but seems to fail when _old style figures_ are passed as an option to the font, ie. `\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}` still prevents the `\emph` nesting.

Comment: @Browaeys In that case you should use `-OsF` instead of `-LF` and `-osf-` instead of `-lf-`. I'll try making a more flexible hack.

Answer (score 6):

That's odd, it looks like something strange in the font metrics fontdimen1 (the font slant) is set to 0 even for the clearly sloped italic font, so `\emph` does not recognise it as being a sloped font.  You can set it as:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\begin{document}

{\itshape \fontdimen1\font=.25pt}


Normal text. \emph{Emphasized text.} \emph{Emphasized text including \emph{emphasized} text.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This workaround (`{\itshape \fontdimen1\font=.25pt}`) still works with `\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}`. 

A (very) small caveat is that it does not work within a `\title` (displayed with `\maketitle`), as it does using @egreg solution.